# Get time difference between two time zones (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have:

any date (GMT+00:00)UTC

```
var d = new Date(y, m, d, h, min, s);
```

and time difference in hours

```
var visitortime = new Date();
var time_offset = visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

How I can calculate new date considering the difference without writing long handmade function?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question please, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: how to calculate date and time in the time zone of the user, when I have time (d) and the difference in hours (time_offset)?

Answer (score -1):

[**SAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/kASDy/):

```
​<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d1 = document.getElementById('d1'),
    d2 = document.getElementById('d2'),
    hours = 3,
    date1 = new Date(),
    date2 = new Date();
    date2.setTime(date1.getTime() + hours * 3600000);
    d1.innerHTML = date1;
    d2.innerHTML = date2;
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add hours to a `Date` instance then you can make use of the [`Date.setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) method.

```
var userTime = new Date();

// Add four hours to the `userTime` date instance.
userTime.setHours(userTime.getHours() + 4);
```

If you wanted to make this re-usable, you could add a new method to the `Date` object's prototype:

```
// Add the supplied number of hours to a Date instance.
Date.prototype.addHours = function (value) { 
    this.setHours(this.getHours() + value);
};
```

You could then simple write:

```
var userDate = new Date();
userDate.addHours(4);
```

If you plan on doing a lot of date manipulation in your code, then it might be a good idea to pull in a date/time library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which includes a number of useful utility methods, and unlike adding new method to the `Date` prototype, your code will remain portable.  Here's how you could add four hours to a Date instance using moment.js

```
var result = moment().add("hours", 4);
```